# How to make call from WebView with Intent

Tags: android

My `WebView` contains a call button.On tapping the button, i get an error that says.

> webpage at tel : could not be loaded because net:err_unknown_url_scheme

This is the code i used. I have used the inner class as suggested by other posts, but it still doesn't work.

```
public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TEL_PREFIX = "tel:";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    WebView webb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webb.setInitialScale(0);
    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webb.loadUrl("http://www.sitecart.in");


     class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webb, String url) {
            url=webb.getUrl();
            if(url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    WebView webb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
    if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {

        if (webb.canGoBack()){

            webb.goBack();
        }
        else {

            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a class for `WebViewClient` but setting another `WebViewClient`. Just do it as follows .

```
 webb.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

And

```
class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:-** `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`
is deprecated in API level 24. Use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)` instead.